# Name of a cartoon with blue, red and yellow monsters that return to tubes when tired

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I need to know I name of this one cartoon. There are monsters, some of them have blue, some of them have red and some of them have yellow energy and when they are tired they return to their tubes.
They are in their tubes and when a character says *name of a monster* SPIN!!! The character uses their fingerprint when they spin the tube, and then the monster comes out. I hope you can help me with this, any suggestions would be  awesome, thanks in advance.
There is one monster called Lock, but I'm not sure on the spelling

Comment: Pokemon? You might want to add some more details, like when you saw this, and where. And was it a western animation, or Japanese/some other?

Comment: Its not pokemon haha but thanks for suggestion, thats the problem,the only thing I can remember is the thing I wrote up there..

Comment: I tried fixing your sentences, but can you clarify the "when a character says *name of monster* SPIN!!" bit? The character vocalizes the name of the monster and yells "SPIN"? And can you clarify what "tube" means?

Comment: @ArthurDent tube (its a place where a monster returns when its master tell him to,tube...tube...how do I expl this to u ,it can fit into a hand ,imagine a can thats very thin..

Comment: So it's basically a pokeball but shaped like a tube? Any specific color?

Comment: @ArthurDent yes,in that cartoon some mosters have blue,some red,some yellow energy that powers them,so the tube is either blue or red or yellow,it depends on a monsters energy

Comment: Roughly when did you watch this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be talking about [Monsuno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsuno):

> The show revolves around "re-awakened Monster DNA called Monsuno" that finds its way into the unsuspecting hands of adventure-seeking teenagers Chase, Jinja, and Bren. Accompanied by their Monsuno, Lock, Charger, and Quickforce, they are searching for Chase's father Jeredy Suno, the creator of the Monsuno.[8] They are soon joined by Beyal, a monk from the Himalayas along with his Monsuno Glowblade. Beyal often speaks of five people that with the help of their Monsuno, could change the world. It just so happens that they are that five, along with Dax, a teenager who along with his Monsuno Airswitch, opposes the team and is disliked among most people. The team has yet to befriend him and persuade him to join their cause. They are also on the run from a H.A.M.M.E.R.-type agency called "S.T.O.R.M." (Strategic Tactical Operatives for Recovery of Monsuno) whose plans are still in question and Dr. Emanuel Klipse, a malevolent scientist who has his own nefarious plans.[9]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're thinking of *[Beyblade](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade)* or one of its sequels? They involve kids fighting using tops that contain monsters.

### Beyblade Burst trailers

Comment: Haha its not beyblade,its not bakugan,its not chaotic,I only remember that there was one monster called lock,but I dont know if thats how u spell it,its read as Lok